# How to withdraw either currency or a percentage of odoo depending on selector

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-14

How to withdraw either currency or a percentage of odoo depending on selector.
**.py**

```
@api.depends('discount_type', 'discount_rate', 'amount_total')
def _compute_amount_discount(self):
    for act in self:
        amount_untaxed = amount_discount = discount_rate = 0.0
        for line in act.reconciliation_act_line_ids:
            amount_untaxed += line.price_subtotal
        if self.discount_type == 'percent':
            amount_discount = amount_untaxed * self.discount_rate / 100
        else:
            amount_discount = self.discount_rate

        act.update({
            'amount_total_with_discount': amount_untaxed - amount_discount,
            'amount_discount': - amount_discount,
            'amount_total': amount_untaxed,
        })
```

**.xml**

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-between">
          <div class="col-4">
              <group name="discount"
                   attrs="{'invisible': [('apply_discount', '=', False)]}">
               <field name="discount_type"/>
               <field name="discount_rate"/>
               </group>
           </div>
           <div class="col-4">
               <group>
                   <field name="amount_total"  nolabel="0" widget='monetary'
                                                   options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                   <field name="amount_discount" widget='monetary'
                                                   attrs="{'invisible': [('apply_discount', '=', False)]}"/>
                   <field name="amount_total_with_discount" widget='monetary'
                                                   attrs="{'invisible': [('apply_discount', '=', False)]}"/>
                   <field name="amount_total_executors" nolabel="0" widget='monetary'
                                                   options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                  </group>
              </div>
         </div>
   </div>
```

I can add a fixed currency, but when I switch to percentages, the currency stays there, of course (widget='monetary')

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the field data-type which I don't recommend. It may have a chance to lose data.

If a field declared with Monetary data-type, it will ignore your xml changes. But if you convert that field into Float and then remove the widget. It should work.

**EDIT**

Add one more field called *discount_rate_percent*. Display that field based on selector. Something like:

```
<!-- $ Discount rate display -->
<label for="discount_rate" attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'percentage')]}"/>
<div attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'percentage')]}">
  <field name="discount_rate" class="oe_inline" attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'percentage')]}"/>
  $
</div>

<!-- % Discount rate display -->
<label for="discount_rate_percent" attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'fixed')]}"/>
<div attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'fixed')]}">
  <field name="discount_rate_percent" class="oe_inline" attrs="{'invisible':[('apply_discount', '=', 'fixed')]}"/>
  %
</div>
```

Comment: fields are declared with the Float type

Comment: I have re-read your question and edit my answer.